# construct datetime index columns using date_parser function

Tags: datetime, pandas, indexing, data-structures, dataframe

I would like to create a datetime index from multiple columns of a dataframe.

Since the datetime input needs to be convertered I am useing a `date_parser` similar to a `date_parser` in [read_csv](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).

I tried to apply the parser function on the dataframe rows. But since it is not vectorised I get an error.

Here's a simplified example:

```
data = """
2015;1;1;4
2015;1;2;4
2015;1;3;4
2015;1;4;4
2015;1;5;4
"""

import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';')
print (df)

def date_parser(year, month, day):
    res = dt.datetime(year, month, day)
    return res

df['dt'] = (myfunc(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1], df.iloc[:,2]))
#or
df['dt'] = df.apply(myfunc(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1], df.iloc[:,2]), axis=1)

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

This one works

```
def date_parser_s(y, m, d):
   r = dt.datetime(y, m, d)

   return r 

string_form = df.apply(lambda r: date_parser_dt(r[0], r[1], r[2]), axis=1)
```

But this one not:

```
string_form = df.apply(date_parser_dt(df[0], df[1], df[2]), axis=1)
```

May you kindly help to with a non-lambda version?

I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is called for each row in the dataframe make it take a row as its argument:

```
def date_parser(ymd):
   return dt.datetime(ymd[0], ymd[1], ymd[2])

data = '''year;month;day;stuff
2015;1;1;4
2015;1;2;4
2015;1;3;4
2015;1;4;4
2015;1;5;4
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';')
df.apply(date_parser, axis=1)

0   2015-01-01
1   2015-01-02
2   2015-01-03
3   2015-01-04
4   2015-01-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```